# How do I get Windows Media Center and Hyper-v running concurrently (on a windows 8 host OS)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center, hyper-v

I have a AMD Radeon HD 3200 based motherboard which I have used as a media center for the last 3-4 years.

I am using the on board graphics (driver version 8.970.100.0) and windows 8 x64 but also want to run a couple of linux VMs under hyperv.

Individually both hyper-v and media center work.

When I try to run media center with hyper-v enabled then I get no video but I can hear audio. If I disable hyper-v and reboot I can see media center fine.

See: http://digitalmediaphile.com/index.php/2012/12/16/a-fix-for-wmc8-hdcp-hyper-v-video-display-conflict/

> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Given that I have some of the latest video drivers is there anything else I can do to get both hyper-v and media center working concurrently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to a later version of media portal and to windows 8.1 fixed the problem.